# Disable Control+Space keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard

By default, in macOS the keyboard shortcut Control+Space is enabled for switching keyboard input method such as Qwerty versus Dvorak.

I cannot remember the way to disable this default behavior. I have a conflict with another app that wants to use the Control+Space keystroke.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Input Sources** and uncheck:

**[] Select the previous input source**

Note that **Input Sources** may only show if you have, or have had, more than one in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Input Sources**

Temporarily add one if necessary.

[image]

Comment: I wonder how to work out doing this with the defaults command?